# How to compare two objects for equality which have a List?

Tags: dart

I have a class

```dart
class Foo {
  final List<int> a;
  final List<int> b;
  Foo(this.a, this.b);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => identical(this, other) || other is Foo && listEquals(a, other.a) && listEquals(b, other.b);

  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(a, b);
}
```

I want to check if two instances of `Foo` are equal with hashCodes.

```dart
final list1 = Foo([0], [0]);
final list2 = Foo([0], [0]);

print(list1 == list2); // Prints true, all good
print(list1.hashCode == list2.hashCode); // Prints false.
```

How to properly override hashCode so that the above print statement also prints `true` without using a third party package?

Comment: Please remember that if the hashCodes are the same, it doesn't necessarily mean the objects are equal.  It can only prove the opposite.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Correct, but in my case, it's the opposite, the instances were equal but the hashCodes were different. So, I needed to know how to properly override the `hashCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you got the `listEquals` method from, should also provide you with a compatible `listHash` function. If it doesn't, you can use [`ListEquality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ListEquality-class.html) from `package:collection`, it also has a `hashCode` method.

Then you can do:

```dart
 int get hashCode => Object.hash(
     const ListEquality().hash(a), 
     const ListEquality().hash(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `hashAll` method to hash a list of all of your objects:

```
int get hashCode => Object.hashAll([...a, ...b]);
```

This should get you the result you want.

```
void main() {
  List<int> a1 = [0];
  List<int> a2 = [1];
  List<int> b1 = [0];
  List<int> b2 = [1];
  
  final simpleHashA = Object.hash(a1, a2);
  final simpleHashB = Object.hash(b1, b2);
  
  final correctHashA = Object.hashAll([...a1, ...a2]);
  final correctHashB = Object.hashAll([...b1, ...b2]);
  
  print(simpleHashA == simpleHashB); // prints false
  print(correctHashA == correctHashB); // prints true
  
}
```

Comment: `Object.hashAll()` will still return different hash codes. Please reread the question and answer accordingly.

Comment: @iDecode `Object.hashAll` should not return different hash codes for `List`s with equal elements.  Why do you think it would?

Comment: @jamesdlin In my code, when I used `Object.hashAll([a, b])`, it was returning me different hashCode.

Comment: @iDecode That wouldn't work, and that's not what this answer is suggesting.  Note the use of the spread operator here.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I'm sorry I overlooked this answer.